# Fancybox inline just not working

Tags: fancybox, inline

(http://www.kamgar.nl/test)

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Tester</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css?v=2.0.6" type="text/css" media="screen" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#popups").fancybox({
                maxWidth    : 800,
                maxHeight   : 600,
                fitToView   : false,
                width       : '70%',
                height      : '70%',
                autoSize    : false,
                closeClick  : false,
                openEffect  : 'none',
                closeEffect : 'none'
            });
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>

        <a id="popups" href="#servicesRecovery">Open</a>

        <div style="display:none;">
            <div id="servicesRecovery">Hello!</div>
        </div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
</body>
```

...I get nothing at all, no error, nothing, what am I doing wrong?!

Someone please help me out with this, as I'm going bald by the minute!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move these:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
```

... **above** your fancybox custom script ... or move your fancybox custom script **below** these lines. It is just a matter or initialization order.

**EDIT**: I just checked your sample website and you are missing a proper `DOCTYPE` and the fancybox CSS file (you added the thumbs CSS file only)

Comment: Thanks JFK! Some eagle eye you have there, all working with your pointers.